# How many days from first day of the current year till today

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I'm trying to get day count of from the first day of the current year till today

For example:
`Today =  24/07/2023`
`FirstDate = 01/01/2023`
`LastDate  = 24/07/2023`
The result is 204 days

Is it possible to get the result with just a query (no stored procedure)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function [`DATEDIFF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-datetime.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-datediff) for this:

```sql
select datediff(day, date '2023-01-01', date '2023-07-24') from rdb$database
```

Result: 204

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/wbKAN8Mt

If you want to dynamically find out the first day of the year from the date, you can use the [`FIRST_DAY`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-datetime.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-firstday) function, but this requires Firebird 4.0:

```sql
select date_val, datediff(day, first_day(of year from date_val), date_val)
from (
  select date '2023-07-24' as date_val from rdb$database
  union all select date '2021-01-02' from rdb$database
  union all select date '2022-12-31' from rdb$database
) a
```

Result:

| DATE_VAL | DATEDIFF |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-04 | 204 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 |
| 2022-12-31 | 364 |

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/gl9n-m0p

As pointed out in the comments by [user13964273](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13964273/user13964273), if you want to know the days since the start of the year, you can also use [`EXTRACT(YEARDAY FROM <value>)`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-datetime.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-extract), because 0 is 1st of January, etc, it will produce the same result as `datediff(day, first_day(of year from date_val), date_val)`:

Modified example:

```sql
select date_val, extract(yearday from date_val)
from (
  select date '2023-07-24' as date_val from rdb$database
  union all select date '2021-01-02' from rdb$database
  union all select date '2022-12-31' from rdb$database
) a
```

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/NVimzbAz

Comment: Isn't `EXTRACT(YEARDAY from date_val)` simpler?..

Comment: @user13964273 You're entirely right, that would be simpler for this case. I'll add an example.